# Loading data before rendering view

Tags: angularjs

I am loading images into a view with my controller. It works, except I have the following error when I load the view :

```
%7B%7Bimage.thumbnail%7D%7D:1 GET http://localhost:9000/%7B%7Bimage.thumbnail%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

Despite, having the error, it works, but I am trying to get rid of it.

Here is what I was doing before :

controller :

```
app.controller("WeddingGalerieCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get(url)
    .then(function(response){
      $scope.images=response.data;
      console.log($scope.images);
    });

})
```

view  :

```
<ul class="list" >
  <li lightgallery class="list-item" ng-repeat="image in images">
    <a href="{{image.big}}">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="{{image.thumbnail}}" alt="" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I tried adding a resolve function so my data would load before the view renders, but I still have the same error.

```
  .when('/gallery/wedding', {
    templateUrl: 'views/gallery.html',
    controller: 'WeddingGalerieCtrl',
    css: ['../styles/galleries.css','../styles/lightgallery.css'],
    resolve: {
        images: function($http) {
            return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    }
  })

app.controller("WeddingGalerieCtrl", function($scope, $http, images) {
  $scope.images = images;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Stupid of me, I just noticed that I added an `src` tag instead of `ng-src` ...